# How to restore the active applications widget in home screen?

Tags: app-widgets

In the home screen of my Galaxy Tab I accidentally deleted the widget which showed me the active applications running in the background. Can anyone tell me how I can restore this?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds to me like you deleted a widget.  Long-press on a home screen, choose Widgets from the popup menu, and see if there's one matching your description.

Answer (score 2):

Try pressing and holding the HOME button (hardware button in the bottom row) - that should pop up a screen listing recently opened apps. I believe the Galaxy Tab's interface has been modified to include a TASK MANAGER button. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are talking about the **program monitor widget**: long press anywhere on your home screen, choose `Widgets` and select the `Program Monitor` from the list.